# No matching function for call error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, call

I don't understand what's wrong here. I've cut what i believe to be the non relevant part of the code to make it easier to read. The debugger shows the error below at the line "check(grid, n, q, coord);". Any help is appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queen.h"

using namespace std;

template<size_t N>
void check(int *grid[N], int& n, Queen *q, int *coord[N])
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    // Init
    int n;

    cout << "Grid size:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int const tn=n;
    Queen q[tn];
    int grid[tn][tn];
    int coord[tn][2];

    cin.get();

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++)
            grid[i][j]=0;
        coord[i][0]=0;
        coord[i][1]=0;
    }

    //...
    check(grid, n, q, coord);
    //...
}
```

Error:
    no matching function for call to 'check(int [(int)tn][(int)tn], int&, Queen [(int)tn], int [(int)tn][2])'

Comment: check needs a pointer to Queen and to coord[N] - you are not passing it pointers.

Comment: wouldnt you specify a value for the template before calling the function?

Comment: @KyleC: It's been legal ever since C89 to pass an array to a function expecting a pointer. This particular conversion is called "decay".

Answer (score 1):

`int grid[tn][tn];` is not an array with a compile-time fixed size. Variable-length arrays in C++ are a GCC extension, not standard C++. That extension is not compatible with C++ templates, as you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

aside from variable lengh arrays is not C++ standard, your template is wrong

```
template<size_t N>
void check(int *grid[N], int& n, Queen *q, int *coord[N])
{
    //...
}
```

should be

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void check(T (&grid) [N], int& n, Queen *q, T (&coord) [N])
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all variable sized arrays are extensions not standard as MSalters pointed out. However assuming your compiler has support for it...

---

The problem is two dimensional arrays decay to double pointers. And the compilers don't seem to recognize those for template deduction. So here for grid you pass `int**` and you expect `int *grid[N]` which fails to deduct the first dimension of the vector.

---

However for this case you can do it like this by providing all dimensions.

```
template<size_t N>
void check(int grid[N][N], int& n, int *q, int coord[N][2])
{
```